# Menu aligning (probably invisible non-hendleable margin)

Tags: html, css

I wanted to align my menu (these redblocks) to center like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISmrm.jpg

So I tried to align it with:

HTML

```
    <div id="main">
    <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">first red block</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">second red block</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">third red block</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">last red block</a></li>
    <ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
nav.menu {
  background: none;
}


nav.menu ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 33px;
}

nav.menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav.menu a {
  line-height: 70px;
}

nav.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
}

#main
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: auto;
    width: 900px;
}

}
```

But the result looks like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgXuE.jpg

I don't know why. The outer element have 900px width, each red block have 200px (4x 200 = 800 ... 100px of free space), and margin-right of red blocks is 33px except last li element. So there must be 1px of free space.

So why the last redblock jumped out of queue? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
nav.menu {
  width: 900px; /*gave it fixed for demo purpose */
  margin:0;
  background: none;
}
.menu ul {
  font-size: 0; /* when child elements are inline-block, they get some extra margin, to remove it, we give parent element font-size:0; or make child elements float;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.menu ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 33px;
  font-size: 14px; /* as parent had font-size:0; give a new font-size value to view text*/
}
.menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
nav.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
}
#main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">first red block</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">second red block</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">third red block</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">last red block</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- your tag wasn't closed, hence last child wasn't working -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! The main problem was that, I forgot to close the ul element.

Comment: @UsopleskCz ya, I noticed it at last, after trying it through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *CSS* [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property together with [justify-content: space-between](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

Here I leave the snippet:

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
}
nav.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
nav.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
/* this makes the magic ************/
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
/***********************************/
}
nav.menu ul li {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav.menu a {
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#1">first red block</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">second red block</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">third red block</a></li>
      <li><a href="#4">last red block</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```